# Magento2 : Show First placed order first in order history

Tags: magento2, orders, customer-account

In My order tab in customer account show last order first
i want there first placed order first.

Comment: Click on order id column name. It will show you list from first order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override function `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History::getOrders()` and change `created date` to `asc` from `desc`

```
public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'asc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```